# split a string on every odd positioned spaces

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have strings of varying lengths in this format:

```
"/S498QSB 0 'Score=0' 1 'Score=1' 2 'Score=2' 3 'Score=3' 7 'Not administered'"
```

the first item is a column name and the other items tell us how this column is encoded

I want the following output:

```
/S498QSB
0 'Score=0'
1 'Score=1'
2 'Score=2'
3 'Score=3'
7 'Not administered'"
```

str_split should do it, but it's not working for me:

```
str_split("/S498QSB 0 'Score=0' 1 'Score=1' 2 'Score=2' 3 'Score=3' 7 'Not administered'",
              "([ ].*?[ ].*?)[ ]")
```

Comment: Maybe split with `"\\s+(?=\\d+\\s)"`? Or even ``"\\s+(?=\\d+\\s+')"``? See https://regex101.com/r/JrAAFF/1

Comment: many thanks Wiktor, any chance you could add it as an answer and help explain how it works?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
str_split(x, "\\s+(?=\\d+\\s+')")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrAAFF/1).

*Details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=\d+\s+')` - a positive lookahead that requires the following sequence of patterns immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `'` - a single quotation mark.

Comment: HI Wiktor, thanks this is great! Unfortunately I've found the data to be a little messier than that I provided. For example: 

/S498QSB 0 'Score=0' "1" 'Score=1' 2 "Score=2" 3 'Score=3' '7' 'Not administered'

Comment: @pluke Then try `str_split(x,'\\s+(?=(?:\\d+|"\\d+"|\'\\d+\')\\s+[\'"])')`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/DI8CXz/1).

Comment: brilliant, thanks! I need to read up on regex!